# Advanced searching in Vim

Tags: search, vim, vi

Is there a way to search for multiple strings simultaneously in Vim? I recall reading somewhere that it was possible but somehow forgot the technique.

So for example, I have a text file and I want to search for "foo" and "bar" simultaneously (not necessarily as a single string, can be in different lines altogether).

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/^joe.*fred.*bill/          : find joe AND fred AND Bill (Joe at start of line)
/fred\|joe                  : Search for FRED OR JOE
```

Comment: This works as well. And is much simpler than the paranthetical answer I gave below

Comment: If only I found this earlier... :(

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found the answer soon after I posted this (yes I did google earlier but was unable to locate it. Probably was just searching wrong)

The right solution is

/(foo\|bar)

@Paul Betts: The pipe has to be escaped

Comment: I think that escaping the pipe is required in some RegExp dialects and not others.

Comment: Yes ... I agree that it's needed in vi, but the escaping of characters is terribly inconsistent and attempting to directly copy that fragment into another implementation must be undertaken with care.

Comment: Yeah it is inconsistent. I will have to check but I don't think Vi follows PCRE (perl compatible regular expressions) where we would not have to

Comment: You need to escape the parens too (in vi(m)).

And there are many, many different regex's out there. Vim's is derived from vi, which in turn is derived from ex. It's terribly inconsistent about special characters, but you can use \v or \V to change the behavior.

Comment: Yes, what @Zathrus said. See `:help magic` for more info, including a table of what needs to be escaped and what doesn't with the various settings enabled. `\v` is "*v*ery magic".

Answer (score 0):

Vim supports regular expressions by starting in command mode with a '/'.

So using something like "/(foo\|bar)" (as was stated before) would solve the problem.  It's good to know why that works and what you are using (regular expressions).

Answer (score -3):

```
/(foo|bar)
```

Comment: by default you need to escape bars and parentheses:  /\\(foo\|bar\\)

but either way, in this case no need to group them!  /foo\|bar