# multiple searching in vim (i'm picky)

Tags: vim, editor

I want to be able to search for multiple strings in vim. There are a number of solutions I've come across, but they all suck:

- [Advanced searching in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131559/advanced-searching-in-vim)
- [Is there any way to highlight multiple searches in (g)vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704434/is-there-any-way-to-highlight-multiple-searches-in-gvim)
- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1183

First off, typing anything other than '/' to begin a search is a fail. ":match SearchName search_string" is really bad. ":Search foo" is bad as well.

So here are my requirements for a good multiple search solution in vim:

1. Must be able to type /
2. Clearing search must be easy
3. Each search should use a different color

Ideally, some other criteria would be met:

1. Should be able to easily clear either last search or all searches
2. Should be able to easily find next result of either last search or any current search
3. Shortcuts * and # should work similarly

If anyone knows of any solution that satisfies these conditions (or at least comes closer than the solutions mentioned above), I'd love to see it.

**Edit:** MultipleSearch2, from one of the links above, did very bad things to a lot of my syntax highlighting. It's nowhere close to useful for me.

Comment: `nnoremap / :Search ` or whatever.

Comment: That might get me a bit closer. See my edit...

Comment: You may want take a look at Mark.vim plugin - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666

Comment: What is the OP's opinion on Mark? It looks promising to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've used MultipleSearch, and the following config from `.vimrc` to some success:

```
:nmap <C-_> :Search
:nmap <C-Bslash> :SearchReset<cr>
:let g:MultipleSearchColorSequence="232,232,232,232"
:let g:MultipleSearchTextColorSequence="51,105,199,228"
```

You should be able to change the mapping for `:Search` to `/` with `:nnoremap / :Search`

Edit: I notice that the `:nnoremap` I mentioned doesn't work from `.vimrc`, but it does work once inside vim. Odd...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:match`, `:2match` and `:3match` builtin commands

These allow arbitrary highlighting colours. To make the workflow automatic (by using the most recently used search patterns) you'll have to work out some mappings that do stuff like (perhaps using the `@/` register directly and doing a smart 'rotational' scheme to get the desired effect.

Note that `match` is *akin to* syntax highlighting, but doesn't actually interfere with it. However, a notable effect is that the `match` hightlights are buffer-local too.

Comment: `:match` is local to the window not the buffer therefore after splitting a buffer the highlights will not be present. This can be rectified with the use of the `WinEnter` event. Also :3match is used by matchparen plugin so undesired side-effects may occur.

Comment: @PeterRincker: thanks for the additional info. Whether 'rectified' is the correct choice of words depends on the OP's requirements :)